# Exporting a sheet to a word table gives a weird outcome

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote this macro to export an Excel sheet into a word table:

```
Private Sub Export_Click()        'export to word table
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Sheets("export").Visible = True       'make hidden sheet visible
Set objDoc = objWord.documents.Add()
LastRow = Sheets("export").Range("$G$1").Value  'number of lines to export
For i = 1 To LastRow
Sheets("export").Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
objWord.Selection.Paste
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False         'clear the clipboard
Sheets("export").Visible = 2       'hide the sheet
End Sub
```

The result is a weird formatted [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu5CJ.png) with cells getting wider and wider toward the bottom, while the original sheet has the same formatting on all the rows and columns.

How can I solve this?

Comment: 1) instead of copying entire row you can just copy the required columns.  2) create table in objword like`objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns` 3) Assign objdoc.tables  `Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)` loop through the table and paste the column and row contents in to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of exporting table row by row, you can copy and paste the whole table at once.

```
Sub Export_Click()
    'export to word table
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Sheets("export").Visible = True       'make hidden sheet visible
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
    lastrow = Sheets("export").Range("$G$1").Value  'number of lines to export

    Range("A1:F" & lastrow).Copy 'mention the number of columns you want to copy

    With objWord
        .Documents.Add
        .Selection.Paste
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False         'clear the clipboard
    Sheets("export").Visible = 2       'hide the sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work better. Only minor issue left is that now the table is not within the margins, but extend till the end of the page.

Comment: How can I force the table to fit within the margins?

Comment: @L.Dutch - I've answered your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339623/forcing-a-table-to-fit-the-margins/37340704#37340704). Check and let me know if its okay.