# Forcing a table to fit the margins

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

the code suggested in the answer to this question ([Exporting a sheet to a word table gives a weird outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499553/exporting-a-sheet-to-a-word-table-gives-a-weird-outcome)) does not make the table fit in the margins, resulting in part of the table being hidden [image]

How can I force the table to fit in the margins?
I have tried `objDoc.Tables.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutofitWindow)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Export_Click()
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim myTable As Word.Table
    Dim myRange As Excel.Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True

    Set myDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

    lastRow = Sheets("export").Range("$G$1").Value  'number of lines to export

    Set myRange = Range("A1:F" & lastRow)
    myRange.Copy

    myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=False, _
        RTF:=False

    Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
    WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False         'clear the clipboard
End Sub
```

This code is based on your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499553/exporting-a-sheet-to-a-word-table-gives-a-weird-outcome).

For above code to run you'll have to add reference of **Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library**. You can do this in `VBE`. In `Tools` menu click `References` and select `Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library`